# How to print the multimap elements having vector?

Tags: c++

I have created the `multimap`.

`multimap<int, std::vector<string> > mt;`.

Also I have inserted the elements to it using:

`mt.insert(std::make_pair(threadid, funcname));`

How to print the elements in multimap using key and value pair?

Comment: What is your problem? Iterating the `multimap`? Printing/formatting the `vector`?

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4850473/) might give you some pointers. Your question could be improved in several ways. You could provide an example of the expected output-format, and describe what you have already tried that didn't work.

Comment: Is `funcname` a vector of strings?

Comment: My problem is printing the vector in multimap?

Comment: I tried using for(multimap<int,std::vector<string>>::iterator t=mt.begin();t!=mt.end();++t)                                           { cout<<first is "<<(*t).first<<endl;}                                  In the similar fashion i want to print the second elemnet of multimap that is vectors. How can I do this? Please help me

Comment: Yes funcname is vector of strings.

Comment: You can iterate over the vector here in a nested loop (`t->second`) the same way as you iterate over a multimap.

Answer (score 2):

You can overwrite `operator<<` for `vector` and `multimap`. Printing code will be looked easier:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

template< class T >
std::ostream & operator << ( std::ostream & os, const std::vector< T > & v ) {
    for ( const auto & i : v ) {
        os << i << std::endl;
    }
    return os;
}

template< class K, class V >
std::ostream & operator << ( std::ostream & os, const std::multimap< K, V > & m ) {
    for ( const auto & i : m ) {
        os << i.first << " : " << std::endl;
        os << i.second << std::endl;
    }
    return os;
}

int main() {
    std::multimap<int, std::vector< std::string > > m;

    m.insert(std::make_pair( 1, std::vector< std::string >( {"one", "two", "three" } ) ) );
    m.insert(std::make_pair( 10, std::vector< std::string >( {"ten", "twenty", "thirty" } ) ) );
    m.insert(std::make_pair( 42, std::vector< std::string >( {"foutry", "two" } ) ) );

    std::cout << m;
}
```

http://ideone.com/LKDPtX

If you don't want to overwrite operator << (I'm wondering why...) you can do it in place:

```
int main() {
    std::multimap<int, std::vector< std::string > > m;

    m.insert(std::make_pair( 1, std::vector< std::string >( {"one", "two", "three" } ) ) );
    m.insert(std::make_pair( 10, std::vector< std::string >( {"ten", "twenty", "thirty" } ) ) );
    m.insert(std::make_pair( 42, std::vector< std::string >( {"foutry", "two" } ) ) );

    for ( const auto & i : m ) {
        std::cout << i.first << " : " << std::endl;
        for ( const auto & i_v : i.second ) {
            std::cout << i_v << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

At the last, if you can't use C++11 (I'm also wondering why...) you can change code like this:

```
int main() {
    typedef std::vector< std::string > strings_t;
    typedef std::multimap<int, strings_t > map_t;
    map_t m;

    {
        strings_t v;
        v.push_back( "one" ); v.push_back( "two" ); v.push_back( "three" );
        m.insert( std::make_pair( 1, v ) );
    }
    {
        strings_t v;
        v.push_back( "ten" ); v.push_back( "twenty" ); v.push_back( "thirty" );
        m.insert( std::make_pair( 10, v ) );
    }
    {
        strings_t v;
        v.push_back( "foutry" ); v.push_back( "two" );
        m.insert( std::make_pair( 42, v ) );
    }

    for ( map_t::const_iterator i = m.begin(), e = m.end(); i != e; ++i ) {
        std::cout << i->first << " : " << std::endl;
        for ( strings_t::const_iterator i_v = i->second.begin(), e_v = i->second.end(); i_v != e_v; ++i_v ) {
            std::cout << (*i_v) << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

http://ideone.com/S80nLj

Comment: Is there any other method other than overwriting the operator <<?

Comment: Yes, it is. Pull out code from operator << and insert it instead of `std::cout << m;`

Comment: I didnt understand what you are saying. can you please make it clear

Comment: I edited an answer. If you can't use C++11, I can do it once more ))

Comment: It is giving error.a function definition is not allowed here befor ':' token for the line                                                  for ( const auto & i : m ) {

Comment: What's with all the unneccessary stream flushes?

Comment: And for the C++98 version a simple `std::copy(i->second.begin(), i->second.end(), std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "\n"));` might be more concise and streamlined than the inner `for` loop.

Comment: @ChristianRau I don't think, that OP must think about optimization here. Isn't it ?

Comment: @borisbn In which way is this an otpimization. It is just clearer, more concise and more streamlined. At what point did I say anything about (performance) optimization (they'll be more or less equally efficient, anyway).

Comment: @ChristianRau you told about "unneccessary stream flushes" and I thought you wanted to avoid them for optimization. The other... maybe I'm too conservative, but I like `for` instead of `copy` + `ostream_iterator`. It's easy to modify cycles afterwards

Comment: @borisbn Ah yes, the flushes, already forgot about those. Well yeah, that could be considered an optimization, but it's not a *premature optimization* because it doesn't bring any complexity to do it the right way in the first place, even more so I'd say `'\n'` is much clearer than `std::endl` anyway (though this might again be our indeed diverging views on conciseness and clarity). In fact *not* doing this the correct way right from the start would be a *premature pessimization*. It is just bad practice taught to many people and is as hard to get right as it is easy to learn wrong...

Comment: ...which is the reason to teach others correctly when possible. And even more than an optimization it is also conceptually wrong. You just don't need to flush the stream there (though there are certain situation when you really want this) and you would in no way have the idea to do so, if not somebody had told you long ago that *"`std::endl` means newline"*. Had I told you *"you need to flush the stream after each newline"* you would wonder *why*, but not only because you fear the possible perfomance loss, but just out of the inherent curiosity to know why you should do something unneccessary.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29917/discussion-between-borisbn-and-christian-rau)

Answer (score 1):

You can use below way.

```
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
multimap<int, std::vector<string> > mt;
vector<string> v;
v.push_back("one");
v.push_back("two");

mt.insert(pair<int, vector<string> >(1, v));

multimap<int, std::vector<string> > ::iterator it = mt.find(1);

if(it != mt.end())
{
    for(size_t i = 0; i < (it->second).size(); i++)
       cout<<(it->second)[i]<<endl;
}

}
```

Output:

```
one
two
```

EDIT:

Replace cout line with below line

```
printf("%s\n", (it->second)[i].c_str());
```

Comment: Thanks much for reply.The last cout statement in the for loop is giving error for me saying error:no match for operator<<

Comment: I have included iostream header file already bt still facing the issue

Comment: Its strange not working for me. Is there any other way to print the ector values since this is not working for me

Comment: cout has to work for std::string. If it is not working, we can use printf. Updated my answer.

Comment: Actually the vector is not string to use c_str function..... The actual multimap is like following......              multimap<int,std::vector<Dyninst::Stackwalker::Frame>> mt;

Comment: In that case, Insertion operator << has to be overloaded with Frame object as parameter and make it friend to Frame class to be able to do cout on that

Comment: Sorry I am very much new into C++ programming. I dunno overloading.Tomorrow I need to show demo on this output but I am not able to print it.

Comment: Ok, you need to show your Frame class so that i can try to give you overload function